# Best practice / way to allow my Azure App Service talk to my Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Azure VM that doesn't have a public IP. It only has a internal IP and it lives in my 'development' environment virtual network on azure. Let's call this **vm-dev** on the virtual network **vnet-dev**.

My Azure VM host a Web API that runs on IIS on localhost on this virtual machine. Let's call it **CoolWebApi**

I have a Azure App Service that is an API that lives on the same environment, let's call it **api-dev**.

api-dev has a virtual IP address, lets call it ***91.195.240.126***

> 1) The only way anyone can get to **vm-dev** is by going through my Azure Firewall. They need a specific NAT rule to allow them access to that vm. For example, I might have a NAT rule that is like below.
>
> > Source IP, Destination IP (Firewall Public IP), Translated Address, Port.
> >
> > 23.44.55.66, 23.674.23.12, **91.195.240.126** (vm-dev lives here), 3389.
> >
> > The problem is, I want to allow my Azure App Service (api-dev) the ability to make requests to this VM on port 8080. So I think, I'll just make another NAT rule in the firewall and use the api-dev virtual IP / outbound addresses as the source IP, that will work right? Wrong.
> >
> > I also tried to create inbound rules on my vnet-dev to allow the api-dev virtual ip on port 8080, 443, that also didn't work!

What is the best practice for this? What *should* I be doing?

At the end of the day, api-dev should be able to make requests to CoolWebApi that lives on vm-dev running on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DNAT rule in Azure Firewall with the Source IP as App Service outbound IPs, and destination IP as Firewall's Public IP and Destination port as "Any IP which is not used by any other service" and translated port as 8080.

You cannot use the same Destination port for 2 DNAT rules.

When you create a DNAT rule, an inbound rule is created implicitly, so you don't necessarily need to create an Network rule here.